# How to make a search form to an external website?

Tags: html

I'm just a beginner at coding but I'm in the process of gaining some experience. For my website, I would like to create a form for flights of a certain airline that I am an affiliate partner of. On the form, the following elements should be present:

- FROM (3 airports in a certain country, the destination is already fixed because that is what the website is about)
- DEPART (date form)
- RETURN (date form)
- Button with "search flights"

The affiliate party doesn't offer a standard form unfortunately, so I have to work on it myself. When I view the website of the airline, a search url is formulated as: `website.com/en-NL/book-a-flight/calendar/viewcalendar/?ds=AMS&as=BAR&om=10&oy=2021&im=10&iy=2021`

However, when I convert this into the link generator for my particular affiliate website it changes to:

`website.com/tickets/?tt=27688_12_298723_&r=%2Fnl-NL%2Fboek-een-vlucht%2Fcalendar%2Fviewcalendar%2F%3Fds%3DAMS%26as%3DBAR%26om%3D10%26oy%3D2021%26im%3D10%26iy%3D2021`

How can I get my form working now? I currently have the following code:

```
<form method=get action="https://www.transavia.com/nl-NL/boek-een-vlucht/vluchten/zoeken/" target="_blank">
<input type=text name= ds ="">
<input type=text name= as ="">
<input type=text name= OD ="">
<input type=text name= OM ="">
<input type=text name=OY value="">
<input type=submit value="Bekijk Vliegtickets">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?  I don't know if it's exactly what your looking for, but I tried my best.

```
var x = document.getElementById(input 1 HTML ID);
var x1 = document.getElementById(input 2 HTML ID);
var x2 = document.getElementById(input 3 HTML ID);
var x3 = document.getElementById(input 4 HTML ID);
var x4 = document.getElementById(input 5 HTML ID);
```

and then call them to your pleasure

also try closing of the `<form>` tag.